# How to automatically add end remarks on swiftui?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

How to automatically add end remarks on swiftui ?

like this :

[image]

Comment: Do you know that it can be done, have you seen it anywhere? Just curious.

Comment: That thing is apple job more about Xcode, we cannot do that!

Comment: @Joakim Danielson    idea can do it on flutter with the size of 1.7G ，and xcode do nothing to more than 25G

Comment: Maybe i can do it by myself with python

Comment: https://github.com/milukun/AutoRemarkXcode

Comment: @capdev and how you integrate this with Xcode?

Comment: @AhmedShendy no need to integrate with xcode. clone the project, and run python main.py in your terminal line.And you can double click AutoRemarkXcode to run without python env